# Preserve names of a list with sapply()

Tags: r, names, sapply

I have the following type of data:

```
token <- list(
cameron = rep("people", 12))
```

I'm applying a function like the following:

```
token <- sapply(token, function(x){
x <- str_trim(x, side = "both")
})
```

The problem is `sapply()` messes up the name of the structure. Running `names(token)` returns `NULL`. Running `str(token)` shows the problem: the first attribute is `NULL` and the second is the one I want as its name. I thought that `USE.NAMES()` would get me what I want, but I can't get it to work. I imagine that this must be a common problem, but I couldn't find the solution here or elsewhere. Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need `simplify=FALSE` in the `sapply`

```
sapply(token, function(x) str_trim(x, side='both'), simplify=FALSE)
```

Or better would be to use `lapply`

```
lapply(token, function(x) str_trim(x, side='both'))
```

Comment: Thanks. `simplify = FALSE` did the trick. I'll look into `lapply()` for this.

Comment: @JoeF `sapply` has that kind of property and if we don't notice to use the `simplify` in a function or so, it may take some time to debug what might be the problem.  So, better use `lapply`.